# Trying to run redisearch-go client example and wont compile

Tags: go, redisearch

When I try to run the code on redisearch-go/client

https://github.com/RedisLabs/redisearch-go

I get the following error.

```
./docsearch.go:37:41: cannot use []redisearch.Document literal (type []redisearch.Document) as type redisearch.Document in argument to c.Index
./docsearch.go:37:41: cannot use redisearch.DefaultIndexingOptions (type redisearch.IndexingOptions) as type redisearch.Document in argument to c.Index
```

I am new to golang but it looks correct to me.

Comment: It appears that the code on the README is not functioning with the current state of the library...see [this pull request](https://github.com/RedisLabs/redisearch-go/pull/7/files) on the repo for a working example.

Comment: That PR has been merged - the docs were indeed wrong.